# Is there a John or Jane Doe in Latin?

Tags: example-request, idiom, names

In English, John Doe or Jane Doe is understood not to be an actual name of a person, but to be some kind of a placeholder name or mean an average citizen.
There are many variants of this name in English and similar names exists in other languages.
[This Finnish Wikipedia page](https://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matti_Meik%C3%A4l%C3%A4inen) lists similar names in various languages — for some reason there is no similar list in the linked English Wikipedia page.

Latin is missing from the list.
Is there a Latin equivalent of the name, either masculine or feminine?
When and how was it used?
I am not looking for suggestions for forming such a name in Latin, but for examples from the literature.
I prefer my Latin classical, but I would be happy to receive examples from any era.

Comment: `there is no similar list in the linked English Wikipedia page` Not sure where you looked, but there is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_placeholder_names_by_language#Latin

Comment: @Earthliŋ, thanks! I hadn't found that page, but it looks useful. That Latin part of the Wikipedia entry together with some citations and use examples would make a great answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

N.N. is still used in Spanish and some other languages. It comes from [*nomen nescio*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomen_nescio). Although it is not a name, it is actually used as if it were.

Also, according to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerius_Negidius), Numerius Negidius was used "in jurisprudence in ancient Rome (...) specifically to refer to the defendant in a hypothetical lawsuit", and was an intentional wordplay to fit N.N.

*See also*: A google search of Numerius Negidius in [The Sources of Roman Law: Problems and Methods for Ancient Historians](https://books.google.cl/books?id=Hg5c7rZe-S0C&pg=PA80&vq=Numerius+Negidius&dq=Numerius+Negidius&source=gbs_search_r&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Numerius%20Negidius&f=false).

Comment: Possibly not the same, but I understood that *Gaius* was used as a  "universal" name. For instance, when a couple married, the bride would say "*Where you are Gaius, I am Gaia *"  and the groom would respond "*Where you are Gaia, I am Gaius*".

Comment: I have read a footnote stating that Aulus Agerius.and  Numerius Negidius were the John Doe and Richard Doe of Roman Law!

Comment: I read only yesterday (in Ostler, 'Ad Infinitum') that the Latin "gaiusque luciusque" was the equivalent of the English placeholder "Tom, Dick and Harry" - see Martial V.14 http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2008.01.0506%3Abook%3D5%3Apoem%3D14